# How to call one external php file and pass the parameters using PHP

Tags: php

I need one help. I need to pass some parameter to another php file and display it using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

**user.php:**

```
<?php
  $product_id=$_POST['product_id'];
?>
```

I need to pass this parameter (`$product_id`) to the following file by calling it.

**saveUser.php:**

```
<?php
  $newCustomerobj->product_id =$_REQUEST['product_id'];

  print_r($newCustomerobj);
?>
```

Here i need to pass the value from `user.php` to `saveUser.php`.Please help me.

Comment: if there is no navigation from user.php to saveUser.php then use session else encode the product it and through query string pass the variable.

Answer (score 1):

If it need not be secure, then pass it as a query string like saveUser.php?id=product_id and access it using $_GET['id'].

Answer (score 0):

If you write a function as following

```
public function functionName($product_id, $variable 2,...)
{
   require_once ('saveUser.php');
}
```

Then usually all variable will get in saveUser.php file. I don't know if it can help you.